# Chromedriver can not launch Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium to automate with chrome, however the browser wont launch.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def login(website_url, username, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'PATH\chromedriver')
         chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.binary_location="../Google Chrome"
   chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars");
   
   driver.get(website_url)
   while(True):
       pass
launchBrowser()

    username_field = driver.find_element_by_id('')
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('')
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    
website_url = ""
username = ""
password = ""
login(website_url, username, password)
```

When I run the chromedriver.exe as Admin it opens a CMD with the following:
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

I was expecting a chrome window to pop up

Comment: Please be careful with your indentation. Most of the presumed lines under the function have inconsistent indentation meaning people have to guess what is part of the function and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium version 4.6.0 and higher, so that you not need to add executable path.
It will directly launch the webdriver.